# Проблема с OlkDateControl в vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

возникла проблема с компонентом 
OlkDateControl  в vba excel. 
Добавил новый компонент через Tools>AdditionalControls, для выбора даты. 
При запуске формы выдает такую ошибку

**"Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focuse"**

В настройках компонента  enabled = true и visible=true

Такая проблема со многими компонентами не только с DateControl

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? 
Зарание спасибо

Comment: Добавляли компонент в этой же версии Excel? Например, будет ошибка, если календарь добавлен в старой версии, но файл открыли в Excel-2010

Comment: Да, в этой же версии

Comment: Нужно видеть пример

Comment: Ну раз *enabled = true и visible=true*, то остаётся единственное - *of a type that does not accept the focuse*. Если его бросить на форму, её запустить, и попытаться переместить на контрол фокус вручную - выполняется? Опять же если верить документации, то *Этот элемент управления невозможно добавить в объект UserForm Visual Basic в редакторе Visual Basic* - не отсюда ли ноги растут?